# Filter nested array of objects based on string

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

Hi everyone I have this array of objects:

```
const example = {
    sections: [
        {
            id: 'something',
            sectionHeader: 'Something',
            content: [
                {
                    contentId: 'something1',
                    contentHeader: 'Lorem ipsum',
                },
                {
                    contentId: 'something2',
                    contentHeader: 'Lorem ipsum',
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            id: 'international',
            sectionHeader: 'International',
            content: [
                {
                    contentId: 'international1',
                    contentHeader: 'Mauris tempus vestibulum',
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            sectionId: 'home',
            sectionHeader: 'Home',
            content: [
                {
                    contentId: 'home1',
                    contentHeader: 'Etiam volutpat rhoncus',
                },
                {
                    contentId: 'home2',
                    contentHeader: 'Curabitur searchedValue mi lectus',
                },
                {
                    contentId: 'home3',
                    contentHeader: 'Orci varius natoque',
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            sectionId: 'city',
            sectionHeader: 'City',
            content: [
                {
                    contentId: 'city1',
                    contentHeader: 'Aliquam cursus',
                },
            ],
        },
    ],
};
```

I want to get a new filtered array based on "search value" in **sectionHeader** or **contentHeader**:

```
const searchValue = 'searchedValue';

const filteredResults = example.sections.filter((section) => section.sectionHeader.toLowerCase().trim().includes(searchValue)
    || section.content.some((content) => content.contentHeader.toLowerCase().trim().includes(searchValue)))
    .filter((section) => section.content.length);
```

The result is the section but with all three content objects (in this case 'home1', 'home2', and 'home3'). The expected result is only the object that contains the searched value ('home2'):

```
{
    sectionId: 'home',
    sectionHeader: 'Home',
    content: [
        {
            contentId: 'home2',
            contentHeader: 'Curabitur searchedValue mi lectus',
        },
    ],
},
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a map and filter to achieve this.

```
example.sections.map((section) => { 
  if(section.sectionHeader.toLowerCase().trim().includes(searchValue)) { 
    return section
  } 
  if (section.content.some((content) => content.contentHeader.toLowerCase().trim().includes(searchValue2))){ 
    let result = {...section}; 
    result.content= result.content.filter((content) => content.contentHeader.toLowerCase().trim().includes(searchValue2)); 
    return result
  } 
  return false;
}).filter(x=>x)
```

Result

```
[ 
  { 
    sectionId: 'home',
    sectionHeader: 'Home',
    content: [ 
               { 
                  contentId: 'home2',
                  contentHeader: 'Curabitur searchedValue mi lectus' 
               } 
             ]
  } 
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written a quick function that will help explain each step which will hopefully put you on the right path. It's been written this way so that I can explain each step more easily.

Steps:

- I've created a function which accepts a search criteria.
- Created a map of all the section headers
- Created a map of all of the section content headers
- Iterated through each section header and see if it matches the search criteria
- If it does, return the whole section
- If it doesn't we'll iterate through the content headers and see if any of the values match our search criteria
- If it does store, these index in an array
- Return the section and overwrite the content key with an array filter that keeps all the indexes where the search criteria returned true on
- Return the results

I've written a more modern version below if you wanted to reduce the line count of the code

```js
const example = {
  sections: [
    {
      id: "something",
      sectionHeader: "Something",
      content: [
        {
          contentId: "something1",
          contentHeader: "Lorem ipsum"
        },
        {
          contentId: "something2",
          contentHeader: "Lorem ipsum"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: "international",
      sectionHeader: "International",
      content: [
        {
          contentId: "international1",
          contentHeader: "Mauris tempus vestibulum"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      sectionId: "home",
      sectionHeader: "Home",
      content: [
        {
          contentId: "home1",
          contentHeader: "Etiam volutpat rhoncus"
        },
        {
          contentId: "home2",
          contentHeader: "Curabitur searchedValue mi lectus"
        },
        {
          contentId: "home3",
          contentHeader: "Orci varius natoque"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      sectionId: "city",
      sectionHeader: "City",
      content: [
        {
          contentId: "city1",
          contentHeader: "Aliquam cursus"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

function search(value) {
  const results = [];
  const sectionHeaders = example.sections.map(section => section.sectionHeader);
  const contentHeaders = example.sections.map(section =>
    section.content.map(content => content.contentHeader)
  );

  example.sections.forEach((_section, index) => {
    const foundIndexes = [];

    if (sectionHeaders[index] === value) {
      return results.push(example.sections[index]);
    }

    contentHeaders[index].forEach((header, index) => {
      if (header.includes(value)) {
        foundIndexes.push(index);
      }
    });

    if (foundIndexes.length !== 0) {
      return results.push({
        ...example.sections[index],
        content: example.sections[index].content.filter((_content, index) =>
          foundIndexes.includes(index)
        )
      });
    }
  });

  return results.length === 0 ? "No results found" : results;
}

console.log(search("searchedValue"));
```

```js
const example = {
  sections: [
    {
      id: "something",
      sectionHeader: "Something",
      content: [
        {
          contentId: "something1",
          contentHeader: "Lorem ipsum"
        },
        {
          contentId: "something2",
          contentHeader: "Lorem ipsum"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: "international",
      sectionHeader: "International",
      content: [
        {
          contentId: "international1",
          contentHeader: "Mauris tempus vestibulum"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      sectionId: "home",
      sectionHeader: "Home",
      content: [
        {
          contentId: "home1",
          contentHeader: "Etiam volutpat rhoncus"
        },
        {
          contentId: "home2",
          contentHeader: "Curabitur searchedValue mi lectus"
        },
        {
          contentId: "home3",
          contentHeader: "Orci varius natoque"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      sectionId: "city",
      sectionHeader: "City",
      content: [
        {
          contentId: "city1",
          contentHeader: "Aliquam cursus"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

function search(value) {
  const results = example.sections
    .map(section => {
      if (section.sectionHeader === value) {
        return section;
      }

      if (
        section.content.some(section => section.contentHeader.includes(value))
      ) {
        return {
          ...section,
          content: section.content.filter(content =>
            content.contentHeader.includes(value)
          )
        };
      }

      return false;
    })
    .filter(Boolean);

  return results.length === 0 ? "No results found" : results;
}

console.log(search("searchedValue"));
```